# Соединение Kinect с Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

Нужно данные от сенсора kinect передать в программу на Arduino, как это проще всего сделать? Очень желательно, чтобы использовался только язык C/C++.

Пока удалось найти лишь упоминания, что это [делается](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rucoding4fun/2012/03/12/kinect-arduino-visual-basic/) на VB, и то там очень мутно всё описано, пока не разобрался.

Вообще конечная цель - сделать, чтобы ардуино-робот поднимал руку, если человек поднимает руку, поднятие руки человеком фиксируется кинектом, робот собран на ардуино, а вот как их стыковать пока не ясно.

Comment: 1. Какие виды соиденений/интерфейсов вы знаете, 2. Какой именно вид соидинения у вас используется? Зная вид интерфейса (соиденения) - выбираются библиотеки или методы для доступа.

Comment: USB? Читайте стандарты USB.

Comment: Вы собрались подключать kinect прямо к aфrduino? Это наверняка не прокатит и вам придется подключать его к отдельному windows компьютеру, а уж с него отправлять команды.

Comment: Если Kinect поддерживает [USB HID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_HID) протокол, то можно подключить через USB Host Shield. Но полноценная поддержка в любом случае вряд ли получится.

Comment: «*Пока удалось найти лишь упоминания, что это делается на VB, и то там очень мутно всё описано, пока не разобрался*». Вы бы лучше привели эти упоминания, может кто поможет разобраться.

Comment: Соединение у нас через USB. Если через винду соединять, то какими средставми лучше воспользоваться? То есть будет одна среда, которая примет сигналы, и вторая, которая как-то их отправит на ардуино. Нам нужна не полноценная поддержка, а просто получить несколько сигналов, чтобы сделать примитивное рукомахание роботу. PS. Добавил в вопрос ссылку на VB вариант, который я пока не до конца разобрал (и там, похоже, без исходников).

Comment: Есть совершенно идиотская идея - сохранять данные с kinect'а в файл, который будет тут же читаться программой на arduino и подавать нужные команды) Если ничего лучше не найду - придётся так и делать...

Comment: @nick_n_a, вы я так полагаю прежде чем записать файл изучаете sata и scsi?

Comment: Интересно, а есть версия arduino которая под виндой работает? Тогда можно было бы использовать какой-нибудь одноплатный PC...

Comment: Вот ещё для информации https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743479/raspberry-pi-with-kinect

Comment: @PavelGridin , можно же записать файл средствами C/C++... Версия ардуино под виндой есть, мы в ней работаем.

Comment: @zcorvid, вы наверное IDE имеете ввиду, я имею ввиду выполнение arduino-программ в windows и использование в них WinAPI